# why dropdown border colour is not showing

Tags: css, react-native

Here i used `native-picker` for dropdown. but css is not applying to the `picker` here is the image  [image]

```
import { Picker } from '@react-native-picker/picker';

<Picker style = { styles.coloring}>
    <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
    <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
</Picker>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 coloring: {
   borderWidth:1,
   borderColor: '#0095ff87',
   width: '100%',
   height :40,
 }
```

Comment: Try adding `borderStyle: solid`

Comment: didn't worked!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your Picker inside a view and give the view a border like this:

```
<View
  style={{
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderColor: '#0095ff87',
  }}>
 <Picker style = { styles.coloring}>
     <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
     <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
 </Picker>
</View>
```